How to get shortcode of an Elementor Custom Widget
I made a custom widget to display cards of some software tools (it renders them and filters them by type, tags... via the Elementor Controls)
Now I'm making the template of taxonomy terms (Taxonomy is type; Term example : "image")
My question is: I'd like to add the shortcode of this widget into the template and adjust it's settings to be able to filter the software cards according to their respective taxonomy terms. But I can't get get it to work. Here is how im using the shortcode in the template:
<?php echo do_shortcode(sprintf( '[custom-wdiget display_type="grid" card_type="mini" number_of_software="-1" filter_type="%s" card_style="light"]', esc_attr($term_slug)  )); ?>
Further details:

Im using Elementor free version
Elementor Version 3.25.3

I thought it's pretty straight forward and included as mentioned above. But apparently it's not the case

You’ll need to take a few steps to get a shortcode for a custom Elementor widget, as Elementor does not natively generate shortcodes for custom widgets. Here’s a guide on creating a shortcode for your Elementor custom widget, allowing it to be used outside the Elementor editor:
public function get_title() {
    return __( 'Your Custom Widget', 'plugin-name' );
}

public function get_icon() {
    return 'eicon-code';
}

public function get_categories() {
    return [ 'general' ];
}

protected function render() {
    echo '<div>Your custom widget content here</div>';
}

For More Details Please Learn : How to get shortcode of an Elementor Custom Widget? [4 Easy Steps]
